# Incrementation in Ruby hashes

Tags: ruby, hashmap

I'm trying to increment the key in a hash. For example. I'm trying to get this

```
{:b => "crayons", :c => "colors", :d => "apples"}
```

to turn into this

```
{:c => "crayons", :d => "colors", :e => "apples"}
```

I thought this code would do the trick but it doesn't. What do I need to change?

```
def hash(correct)
  mapping = correct.each{|key, element| key.next}
  Hash[correct.map {|key, element| [mapping[key], element]}]
end
```

Comment: In general, it's not a good idea to use symbols like variables and create new ones programmatically.

Comment: To extend Mark's comment, that's because the memory allocated to `Symbol` objects is never garbage-collected.

Answer (score 5):

Using `Enumerable#each_with_object`

```
def hash_correct(hsh)
  hsh.each_with_object({}) { |(k,v), hsh| hsh[k.succ] = v }
end

hash_correct({:b => "crayons", :c => "colors", :d => "apples"})
# => {:c=>"crayons", :d=>"colors", :e=>"apples"}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
def hash(correct)
  Hash[correct.map{|key, element| [key.next, element]}]
end
```

Answer (score 2):

```
h = {:b => "crayons", :c => "colors", :d => "apples"}

h.keys.map(&:succ).zip(h.values).to_h
  #=> {:c=>"crayons", :d=>"colors", :e=>"apples"}
```

If the intent were to modify (not keep) the original hash, the update could be done in place:

```
keys = h.keys.reverse
keys.each { |k| h[k.succ] = h[k] }
h.delete(keys.last)
```

which could be inscrutablized to:

```
h.delete(h.keys.reverse.each { |k| h[k.succ] = h[k] }.last)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def hash(correct)
  exp_hash = correct.map { | k, v|  {k.next => v}  }
  Hash[*exp_hash.collect{|h| h.to_a}.flatten]
end

correct = {:b => "crayons", :c => "colors", :d => "apples"}
```

Comment: If you use `k.to_s`, don't you want `k.to_s.next.to_sym`?  As it stands, this returns `{"c"=>"crayons", "d"=>"colors", "e"=>"apples"}`.

Comment: Thanks @CarySwoveland. Actually in ruby 1.8.7 **next** method is not available for **Symbol class** and this is reason why it was first converted to string. Anyways I have modified this answer now for ruby 1.9.3 environment. And thanks you for letting me know :)

Comment: @cvibha What on the *earth* preventing you to get the latest Ruby version. I don't know why lots of people still in *1.8.7*. Please upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

> I thought this code would do the trick but it doesn't.
>
> ```
> mapping = correct.each{|key, element| key.next}
> ```

If you go to the ruby Symbol docs and click on the link for next()...surprise there is no entry for next, but the description at the top of the window says:

> succ
>   Same as sym.to_s.succ.intern.

From that you have to deduce that next() is a synonym for succ().  So Symbol#next/succ converts the symbol to a string by calling to_s().  Well, you know that you are going to get a String returned from to_s, and no matter what you do to that String, e.g. calling String#succ on it, it isn't going to effect some Symbol, e.g. your hash key.  Furthermore, if you look at the docs for String#succ, it says

> succ -> new_string

...so String#succ creates another String object and calling intern() on that String object, and by the way intern() is just a synonym for to_sym(), once again won't affect some Symbol...and it won't even affect the String object returned by to_s.

Finally, intern() doesn't change the second string object but instead returns a Symbol:

```
                  a String
                    V
key.next => key.to_s.succ.intern => Symbol
                         ^
                       another String
```

...and because you didn't do anything with the Symbol returned by intern(), it is discarded.